# Can bigquery tables be accessed through .hql file which will run on dataproc

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to access a `BigQuery` table from my `.hql` file that I will be running on a `Dataproc` cluster.
I have written the code below to set the tables as variables in the `Hive` environment:

```
Set hivevar:source_table_name=project_id:dataset_name:table_name;

Set hivevar:destination_table_name=project_id:datasetname:dest_tablename;
```

Then I wrote a query to insert the output into the table present in `BigQuery`.

```
Insert into ${destination_table_name} select count(*) from ${source_table_name} where name like 'A%';
```

After running the job from Dataproc I am getting an error "table not found". But the table is present in BigQuery dataset.

Can someone please help in resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you post the complete error please?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access `BigQuery` tables in the `Hive` environment. When you run this query, Hive searches for the alias you provided in it's own tables list and not in the `BigQuery`'s tables.

In this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hive-bigquery-storage-handler) you can find a a package that allows you to connect `BigQuery` and `Hive`.

As you can see in the description:

> This is a Hive StorageHandler plugin that enables Hive to interact
> with BigQuery. It allows you keep your existing pipelines but move to
> BigQuery. It utilizes the high throughput BigQuery Storage API to read
> data and uses the BigQuery API to write data.
>
> The following steps are performed under Dataproc cluster in Google
> Cloud Platform. If you need to run in your cluster, you will need
> setup Google Cloud SDK and Google Cloud Storage connector for Hadoop.

I holp it helps